# jquery AJAX load called again in loaded file

Tags: jquery, ajax, load

I have main file with this content(in jQuery):

```
var url = "ajax/edit.php?ID=" + actID + "&&userID=<?=$userID?>"
$('#ajaxAct').load(url);
```

The html and script content in edit.php is successfully loaded, but in the file edit.php I'm trying to load again but this time in vain.

This is what I got in edit.php:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

$('.remove_activity').click(function(e) {
    var url = "remove.php?activityID=" + actID + "&&userID=<?=$userID?>";

    $('#ajaxAct').load(url);   

    alert("test");      

    });     
}); 
</script>
```

It looks like it wasn't possible to call AJAX in this external file. 
Test alert works only without the line

```
$('#ajaxAct').load(url);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `edit.php` you should remove the `$(document).ready` wrapper:

```
<script>
    $('.remove_activity').click(function(e) {
        var url = "remove.php?activityID=" + actID + "&userID=<?=$userID?>";
        $('#ajaxAct').load(url);   
        alert("test");      
    });     
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. you can change it

   ```
   var url = "ajax/edit.php?ID=" + actID + "&&userID=<?=$userID?>"
   $('#ajaxAct').load(url, function() {
       // when it's loaded
       $('.remove_activity').click(function(e) {
           var url = "remove.php?activityID=" + actID + "&&userID=<?=$userID?>";
           $('#ajaxAct').load(url);   
           alert("test");      
       });  
   });
   ```

   to bind event after loading
2. another posibility is to use [getScript()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) but you have to put this part

   ```
   $('.remove_activity').click(function(e) {
       var url = "remove.php?activityID=" + actID + "&&userID=<?=$userID?>";
       $('#ajaxAct').load(url);   
       alert("test");      
   });
   ```

in external file, like `ajax/edit_script.js`